# How to configure TeamCity e-mail notification via SSL connection?

Tags: java, ssl, continuous-integration, teamcity, email-notifications

I've configured TeamCity e-mail notification to use Secure connection SSL. All parameters - host, port, login/pwd specified. Same parameters work for SVN e-mail notification, so it's not a problem.
During connection test, TeamCity says:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: XXX, port: YYY;
nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: 
PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

What should I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by missed certificate. Here is the steps how to fix it:

1) Get the client certificate from your mail server. [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/97201/how-to-save-a-remote-server-ssl-certificate-locally-as-a-file#) is the instruction how to do it. Copy all the stuff between `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` and save it into **email.cer** file. Footer and header should be also copied.

2) Download [Portecle](https://sourceforge.net/projects/portecle) tool.

3) Go to your **TeamCity folder**\jre\bin and run from there:

```
 java -jar D:\portecle\portecle.jar
```

4) In Portecle tool open keystore at **TeamCity folder**\jre\lib\security\cacerts. It will ask the password, default is **changeit**.

5) Import your **email.cer** and save changes.

6) Restart your Team City server.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a jre directory within the TeamCity Server docker container. Any idea how to configure this certificate store within the docker container?